# What is a "Web tailer"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

Yet another question from Salinger's *Ocean Full of Bowling Balls*. Holden writes to his brother from a camp:

> Ask him if he ever read corinthans. Corinthans is in the bible and is very good and pretty and Web tailer read me some of it.

What does "Web tailer" here refer to? Is this a cultural reference, a typo, or a religious concept/post?

Full context can be found [here](http://www.rulit.net/books/three-stories-unpublished-read-318497-3.html)

Google didn't give much due to the popularity of words "web" and "e-tailer". Google Books search wasn't fruitful either.

Comment: Seems like it's someone's name

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Web tailer" does not really mean anything in English, and reading the story in context doesn't illuminate much. Given that the fragment of the letter that they're reading contains multiple deliberate spelling and grammatical errors, I would guess that this is a garbled form of someone's name, *Web Tailer*. *Web* is probably short for *Webster*, an old-fashioned first name, and *Tailer* could be a misspelling of the very common last name *Taylor*.

Comment: *Webb* is another possible first name.